# Python and Opencv attempting to export contour data as list

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to build a digital distance sensor using a camera hooked up via a RCA to USB adapter. I have the camera working and all of the overlays added to it, but my issue seems to be a pure python problem that I can't find a solution for.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    # gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    buf2 = cv2.resize(buf1, (1280, 720))
    buf3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(buf2, (5, 5), 0)
    buf4 = cv2.cvtColor(buf3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    buf5 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(buf4, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(buf5, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cx_data = []
    cy_data = []

    for cnt in contours:
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        if M['m00'] is None or M['m00'] == 0:
            cx = 1
            cy = 1
        else:
            cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
            cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        print(cx, cy)
        cx_data.append(cx)
        cy_data.append(cy)
    cv2.imshow('buf5', buf5)


    # Display the resulting frame
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break



# When everything done, release the capture
print(cx_data)
print(cy_data)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to add the cx and cy (the x and y dimensions of the contour in pixels) to two separate lists named cx_data and cy_data. The issue that I have is that not all of the points are being added to the list. I'll include the output from the console as well.

[image: I couldn't figure out how to copy the output from the anaconda terminal window.]

Also I am sorry if my inexperience with python lists offends anyone.

Comment: _I am sorry if my inexperience with python lists offends anyone._ Don't be sorry, man, you are trying to learn, that's why you are asking for help. While I can't help you with your programming problem, I must encourage you to never apologize for trying to improve. That's always admirable. Good luck, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `cx_data = []` and `cy_data = []` before the `while` loop.

For instance:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cx_data = []
cy_data = []

while(True):
    .
    .
    for cnt in contours:
        .
        .
        cx_data.append(cx)
        cy_data.append(cy)
```

Then the problem should be resolved. Since Each time you get the frame, you re-initialize the `cx_data` and `cy_data` therefore you are losing the data.

Comment: Glad, if I could help :)